# String Pyramid with user input

Tags: c++, string, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to read in a string and output it as a pyramid. I'm not concerned about the shape of the pyramid yet, I just want the string to output correctly. I listed an example of how I want the output to look like in my example code below. I would appreciate any help I can get, thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

//Letter Pyramid
//Ask user for input
//Use loops to display user input as pyramid
//User String "12345"
/*
      1
     121
    12321
   1234321
  123454321
*/

int main()
{
    //Store user input
    string user_input;
    string pyramid;
    string new_str;


    cout<< "Say Something"<<endl;

    getline(cin,user_input);
    cout<<endl;

    for(int i = 0; i <= user_input.length(); i++)
    {
         pyramid = user_input.substr(0,i);
         //cout<<pyramid<<endl;

         for(int j = user_input.length()-1; j >=0; j--)
         {
             new_str = pyramid + user_input[j];

             if(user_input[i] == ' ')
                {
                    user_input.erase(i,1);
                }
          }

                cout<<new_str<<endl;

      }



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will produce your desired result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

//Letter Pyramid
//Ask user for input
//Use loops to display user input as pyramid
//User String "12345"
/*
      1
     121
    12321
   1234321
  123454321
*/

int main()
{
    //Store user input
    string user_input;
    string pyramid;
    string new_str;


    cout<< "Say Something"<<endl;

    getline(cin,user_input);
    cout<<endl;

    int ln = user_input.size() , mxLen = ln + ln - 1 ;
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= ln ; i ++) {
        // printing spaces
        for(int space = 1 ; space <= ln - i ; space ++) cout << ' ' ;
        // printing first half of string
        for(int ch = 0 ; ch < i ; ch ++) {
            cout << user_input[ch] ;
        }
        if(i >= 2) {
            // printing right sight of the string
            for(int ch = i - 2 ; ch >= 0 ; ch --) cout << user_input[ch] ;
        }
        cout << endl ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```